# Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;

Tags: java, email

Im trying to send a mail from my SMTP mail server. While doing with the spring based code it is working perfectly. But when am trying to send through the java code, Here is my java code:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class Test1 {

  Properties emailProperties= new Properties();
  Session mailSession;
  MimeMessage emailMessage;

  public static void main(String args[]) throws AddressException,
      MessagingException {

    Test1 javaEmail = new Test1();
    javaEmail.setMailServerProperties();
    javaEmail.createEmailMessage();
    javaEmail.sendEmail();
  }

  public void setMailServerProperties() {

    String emailPort = "587";
    String host = "mysmtphost";
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", emailPort);

  }

  public void createEmailMessage() throws AddressException,
      MessagingException {
    String[] toEmails = { "tomail.com" };
    String emailSubject = "Java Email";
    String emailBody = "This is an email sent by JavaMail api.";


    mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(emailProperties, null);
    System.out.println("mailSession"+mailSession);
    emailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

    for (int i = 0; i < toEmails.length; i++) {
      emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmails[i]));
    }

    emailMessage.setSubject(emailSubject);
    emailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");//for a html email
    //emailMessage.setText(emailBody);// for a text email

  }

  public void sendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException {

    String emailHost = "mysmtphost";
    String fromUser = "myusername";
    String fromUserEmailPassword = "mypassword";

    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");

    transport.connect(emailHost, fromUser, fromUserEmailPassword);
    System.out.println("connected to server");
    transport.sendMessage(emailMessage, emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
    System.out.println("Email sent successfully.");
  }
}
```

And when im running as java application am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
    class javax.mail.SendFailedException: 554 5.7.1 <unknown[172.18.140.85]>: Client host rejected: Access denied
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:926)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:389)
at com.cmc.test.Test1.sendEmail(Test1.java:76)
at com.cmc.test.Test1.main(Test1.java:28)
```

im getting the line "connected to server" in my console.

Please help me, If anybody have come across this type of problem.
Awaiting for the response.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The message is pretty clear:

```
class javax.mail.SendFailedException: 554 5.7.1 <unknown[172.18.140.85]>: Client host rejected: Access denied
```

You have to add authentication information.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.But i tried with the authentication info too. Here is the code :mport java.util.Properties;

Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
   protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
   }
    });   same exception getting while adding the above code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick reply.
But i tried with the authentication info too. Here is the complete code :

```
public class TestMail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String username = "myuser";
        final String password = "mypassword";

        boolean debug = false;

        Properties props = new Properties();
          props.put("mail.smtp.host", "myhost");
          props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
          props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
          props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
          props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");


        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(myuser, mypassword);
            }
          });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("frommail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("tomail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

same exception getting while adding the above code